# How to disable regex in Atom

Tags: javascript, regex

I am new to stackoverflow and this is my first question ever.

I have the problem that if I want to use a pathname that anything that starts with \s or any regex identifier gets keyed out and that I can't use the pathnime. I googled for a while and also checked a few stackoverflow question but I couldn't find anything, could be due to bad searching with keywords or there is nothing.

Using node.js and javascript for this.

```
sftp.connect({
  host: '*******',
  port: '*******',
  username: '*******',
  password: '*******'
}).then(() =>{
  return sftp.list('C:\servers\squad_server\SquadGame\ServerConfig');
}).then(data => {
  console.log(data, 'the data info');
}).catch(err =>{
  console.log(err, 'catch error');
});
```

Comment: I really don't know if you can customize Atom in this way

Comment: do you know how I could fix it then?

Answer (score 0):

I just used / instead of \, didnt know you were allowed to do that when it comes to directories!